# Is it necessary to make `AtomicBoolean` also `volatile`?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, atomic, atomicboolean

My understanding: Declaring a variable `volatile` guarantees the *visibility* for other threads about writes to that variable. Essentially, every `write` to volatile variable *happens-before* subsequent `reads`.

I understand the atomicity of `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet()` and how it provides the atomicity of `read+write` operation that `volatile` doesn't. But I don't see any doc providing *visibility* guarantee by `AtomicBoolean` like the following:

1. Every successful `write` by `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet()`  will eventually be visible to subsequent `AtomicBoolean.get()` and `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet()` by other threads.

But, I keep seeing code labelled as `thread-safe` which are like this,

```
// default false so that first-thread that execute() can enter the logic block
private static final  AtomicBoolean executing = new AtomicBoolean(false);


public void execute() {
    if (executing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {  // check if the executing is previously false and if so update it to true
        try {
            // thead-safe code, i.e only one thread guaranteed to execute at any point of time time
        } finally {
            executing.set(false); // executing thread now re-sets the test value
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the variable `executing` also declared `volatile`, like `private static volatile  AtomicBoolean executing = new AtomicBoolean(false);` ? So the visibility guarantee needed by `AtomicBoolean` is achieved?

Comment: `volatile` is for changes in the *variable*. That is, if anything else is assigned to `executing`. If it is only assigned in the initializer, and never changed, marking it as `volatile` is irrelevant. What you want is the visibility of the content of the object that it refers to, not the visibility of the variable itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks. Now it makes sense. So if one wants to make the visibility of changes in an object, one would have to make the object mutable but thread-safe, and thats what `AtomicBoolean` can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to make `AtomicBoolean` also `volatile`?

No.

In the example, `executing` is declared as `static final`, so it will be initialized once at class initialization time and safely published to any other code that needs it.

This behavior is guaranteed because there is a *happens-before* between a classes initialization completing (normally) and any subsequent use of any static variable declared by the class.  The fact that the variable is also `final` excludes any subsequent assignments to the static that would negate the *happens-before*.

You would only need to declare `executing` as `volatile` if something could assign a new value to it after initialization.  That's not possible here without doing some nasty reflection.  (And the JLS states that if you do that kind of thing to change a `final`, the memory model guarantees do not apply.)

---

You would get a similar effect if `executing` was `final` but an instance field rather than a `static` field.  The reasoning is slightly different, but it is also explicitly mentioned in the JLS.

---

Finally, the Java syntax does not allow you to combine `volatile` and `final` modifiers.  That combination doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

We **cannot** use the below code

```
private static volatile final AtomicBoolean executing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

Usage of **volatile and final together is invalid**. As stated by @RealSkeptic var which would never change (final) need not have volatile. Volatile is used for those vars whose values gets changed in runtime by one or more thread.

//Happy learning